# I override newQuery with my custom newQuery function in laravel model. In specific function i wanna skip the condition of custom newQuery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, phpmyadmin, eager-loading

Custom new query function in the model :
I used
protected $with = ['newQuery']; in model

```
   public function newQuery(){
        $query = parent::newQuery();
        $query->where('slug','!=', "example");
        return $query;
    }
```

I want to disable this custom NewQuery function in the specific function. I used it without(newQuery) But it's not working,

Comment: Are you just trying to add a where condition to all queries on a model?

Comment: Have you tried the "withoutGlobalScope"?

Comment: `WithoutGlobalScope` woudn't work for this case since overriding the `newQuery` method does not count as a query scope but it hints at the solution (moving this logic to its own global query scope).

Comment: Thank you, everyone, I used WithoutGlobalScope and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not override `newQuery()`. If you want to have a condition that runs with every single query you make (to that model) you should create a separate query scope

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('filter-examples', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('slug', '<>', 'example');
        });
    }
}
```

With this, you can define many global scopes. If you want to run a query without that scope, you can use the `withoutGlobalScope(scope)` method

```php
$results = YourModel::withoutGlobalScope('filter-examples')->get();
```

[More information](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes)